# How can I draw an image from a pixel-by-pixel color array?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vml

Is there any way to draw an image from a color array using VML?
I have the array of color codes for every pixel in a compressed order.  I want to render this with VML using a method like `putImageData()` in canvas.

Answer (score 0):

There's no similar function for VML.  You can load an image using `<v:image>` with a `src` attribute, but there's no support for anything like the canvas ImageData functions at all.  Even [ExplorerCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) doesn't support them (for the same reason).